# Separating comma delimited text within a field using Python

Tags: python, csv, rdf, linked-data

I'm currently trying to convert a table into RDF using Python and attach the values from each cell to the end of a URL (eg E00 becomes statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/E00).

I can do this for cells containing a single value using the script.

```
FirstCode = row[11]

if row[11] != '':

RDF = RDF + '<http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/' + FirstCode + '>.\n'
```

One field within the database contains multiple values that are comma delimited.
The code above therefore returns all the codes appended to the URL

e.g. `http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/E00,W00,S00`

Whereas I'd like it to return three values

```
statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/E00
statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/W00
statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/S00
```

Is there some code that will allow me to separate these out?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is the `split` method.

```
FirstCode.split(",")
```

will return a list like `(E00, W00, S00)`

You can than iterate over the items in the list:

```
 for i in FirstCode.split(","):
      print i
```

Will print out:
E00
W00
S00

[This page](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) has some other useful string functions

Comment: `print RDF + '<http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/' + i+ '>.\n` instead of `print i` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in FirstCode.split(','):
    RDF = RDF + '<http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/' + i + '>.\n'
```